# Accessing array being a member variable

Tags: php, smarty

```
class MyClass {
    public $myMember = ['key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'key2'];
}

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->assign('object', new MyClass());
$smarty->assign('member', 'myMember');
$smarty->assign('key', 'key1');
```

How can I access `$object->$member.$key` in my Smarty template without introducing a new variable?

Straight forward `{$object->$member.$key}` results in an error (I guess `.` has higher precedence than `->`?)

I would like something that doesn't involve introducing a new variable, hence not the obvious `{$temp=$object->$member}{$temp.$key}`

Comment: does `{{$object->$member}.$key}` work?

Comment: No, Smarty gives syntax error on the `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no standard method to do that.

When you use:

```
{$object->$member|var_dump}
```

Smarty knows that it's an array and shows it values but I don't know any method to access element of this array.

However what you can do is to create [Smarty modifier:](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl)

```
// modifier.get.php
function smarty_modifier_get($array, $index)
{
    return $array[$index];
}
```

register your plugin dir:

```
$smarty->addPluginsDir('myplugins');
```

and then you can use syntax:

```
{$object->$member|get:$key}
```

Of course you can change get to something shorter if you will use it often if you need.

But there is also other thing I should mention in reply. I've never used such assignment to use properties of object as variables or keys as variables.

In this case also you can simple assign to Smarty array:

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$smarty->assign('array',$obj->myMember);
```

and then in Smarty you could manipulate standard array without complex syntax or modifiers. So maybe you should consider it but of course it's up to you.